# How to properly Assert calling a React function using Jest

Tags: reactjs, typescript, testing, jestjs

I've been trying to test if a React function has been called  on Click but i always get the same result :

```
  Expected number of calls: >= 1
  Received number of calls:    0
```

And the test fails, this is my Setup,
This is MyComponent

```
import React from 'react';

export default function MyComponent() {
  function handleClick() {
    console.log('Clicking');
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Click</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And here is my Jest Test

```
import { render, screen, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react';
import MyComponent from './MyComponent';

describe('It should run the tests', () => {
  it('Should call the funct', () => {
    //Arrange
    render(<MyComponent />);
    const handleClick = jest.fn();
    const button = screen.getByRole('button');

    //Action
    fireEvent.click(button);

    //Assert
    expect(handleClick).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

This works normally on the app, it does call the function and logs 'Clicking'
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined the mock function but you're Component doesn't know anything about it since it's defined within the component.

What you could do is pass the `onClick` as a prop to the `Component`. This way you could pass any handler function required for the Component as a prop.

```
import React from 'react';

export default function MyComponent({ onClick }) { //  receive as a prop
  /* function handleClick() {
    console.log('Clicking');
  } */
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={onClick}>Click</button> {/*  call the prop */}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Update test:

```
import { render, screen, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react';
import MyComponent from './MyComponent';

describe('It should run the tests', () => {
  it('Should call the funct', () => {
    //Arrange
    const handleClick = jest.fn();
    render(<MyComponent onClick={handleClick} />); //  pass the mock
    const button = screen.getByRole('button');

    //Action
    fireEvent.click(button);

    //Assert
    expect(handleClick).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the Answer dude, So I would have to refactor my Code, since I can't test a function thats happening on the same Component, it's a bit odd i gotta say.

Comment: Agreed. Instead of mocking, assert for things that should happen when the user clicks the button. Like a popup should show, something should increment. This latter approach is what react-testing-library promotes. [Read more](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/how-to-know-what-to-test#how-does-this-apply-to-react)